# c# putting inputs into next array elements automatically

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to put text or variables into the next array element without directly referencing what array element you want it in? For example:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = array[0];
}
```

How could I get this to instead put it into element 0 but every time the button is clicked it automatically puts it into the next available one, array[0] then array[1].

My goal for this is that I have a large portion of code that only works for one array element but if I could automatically send the input into the next element I can just redirect each event handler to a new method containing the portion of code which would save me from just copy and pasting the code 5 times and just changing the element ID's.

Comment: Your code is not putting the value inside the array, it is *actually* assigning the array's value to `TextBox`. Is that what you want or you want other way round like `array[0] = TextBox1.Text;`

Comment: Simple state-based programming. Have an index that you increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a field called indexValue of type integer and increase it on every click event. For example:

```
private int indexValue; // defines a field to keep the current index

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    array[indexValue++] = TextBox1.Text; // assigns the value entered by the user to the array on the next position
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `List<string>` array instead of `string[]` array

Example code:

```
private List<string> array = new List<string>();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    array.Add(TextBox1.Text);
}
```